# Consistent estimator of the expectation of a conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, monte-carlo, conditional-expectation

I'm stuck in a problem where I have distribution distribution $P(\boldsymbol{x})$, from which I know how to sample from (i.i.d.) and two functions of the random variable $\boldsymbol{x}$: $E(\boldsymbol{x})$ and $A(\boldsymbol{x})$ (both uninvertible). The aim is to compute the conditional mean of $A$ given $E$, $\mathbb{E}[A|E]$.

The question is how to do it.

Specifically, I'm writing that

$$P(A|E) = 
\int P(\boldsymbol{x},A|E)d\boldsymbol{x} =
\int P(A|\boldsymbol{x},E)P(\boldsymbol{x}|E)d\boldsymbol{x} =
\frac{1}{P(E)}\int P(A|\boldsymbol{x},E)P(E|\boldsymbol{x})P(\boldsymbol{x}) d\boldsymbol{x}$$

I then use $P(A|\boldsymbol{x}) = \delta(A-A(\boldsymbol{x}))$ ($\delta$ is the Dirac-delta) to write

$$\mathbb{E}[A|E] = 
\int A P(A|E) dA = 
\frac{1}{P(E)}\int \int A \delta(A-A(\boldsymbol{x}) P(E|\boldsymbol{x})P(\boldsymbol{x}) d\boldsymbol{x} dA
$$
Integrating the $\delta(A-A(\boldsymbol{x}))$ out, and using $P(E|\boldsymbol{x}) = \delta(E-E(\boldsymbol{x}))$ leads to

$$\mathbb{E}[A|E] = \frac{1}{P(E)}\int A(\boldsymbol{x}) \delta(E - E(\boldsymbol{x})) P(\boldsymbol{x}) d\boldsymbol{x} \equiv \frac{I(E)}{P(E)}$$

Both $P(E)$ and $I(E)$ are consistently estimated (denoted as $\overline{P}$ and $\overline{I}$) by the calculation of a multidimensional integral using Monte Carlo. However:

1. is $\overline{I}/\overline{P}$ a consistent estimator of $\mathbb{E}[A|E]$?
2. How do I compute the error estimate of this estimator? $\overline{I}$ is not independent of $\overline{P}$...
3. What is the error estimate of this estimator if $\boldsymbol{x}$ are now correlated?

Comment: I don't see how $P(E|x)$ can possibly equal $\delta(E - E(x))$, as what happens if $\delta > 0$ and $E < E(x)$ or the reverse?

Comment: I forgot to mention that $\delta$ is the [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), $\int P(E|x) dE = 1$. $E < E(x)$ implies $\delta(E - E(x)) = 0$. Does this answer you question @jbowman?

Comment: Yes it does.  In that case, is $E$ invertible, as in can you calculate $x | E(x)$?  If so, then given $E$ you can calculate $x$ then $A(x)$.  I assume not, but just checking...

Comment: yap, $E$ is not invertible. I incorporated both comments in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Why is your first formula $P(A|E)$ correct? When you marginalize out a variable, you either integrate joint only, or integrate a conditional (of that variable) times prior, but not the joint times prior.

Comment: @Barmaley.exe, you are right. The intermediary step had a mistake. I wanted to integrate the joint and write it as the product of the marginal and the prior. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what functions you are using (I am assuming that they are not stochastic here) but this is the way I would deal with the problem:

1. Instead of defining $P(E|X)$ as a Dirac Delta, define it as a discrete probability distribution such that 
   $$
   P(E=E(x)|x)=\begin{cases}
   1\;\;\mathrm{if}\;\;E=E(x) \\
   0\;\;\mathrm{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
   $$

This makes sense since because $E(x)$ is a function you know the value of $E$ with 100% certainty once you know $x$.  As suggested in your comment (A), you can express the above distribution as the Kronecker delta;
$$
\delta_{E,E(x)} = P(E=E(x)|x)
$$
 2. Using Bayes Theorem...
$$
P(X|E) =  \frac{P(E=E(x)|x)P(X)}{P(E)} = \delta_{E,E(x)} \cdot \frac{P(X)}{P(E)}
$$
The key here is that the support for $P(X|E)$ is a subset of the support for $P(X)$.  i.e. Let $x \in \mathcal{X}$ and $x|E \in \mathcal{X_E}$ where $\mathcal{X_E} \subseteq \mathcal{X}$.  Note that for this particular problem the Kronecker Delta $\delta_{x \in \mathcal{X_E}}$ is equivalent to  $\delta_{E,E(x)}$.*

You can then define

$$
P(E) =\begin{cases}
 \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X_E}} P(x)\;\;\mathrm{if}\;\;\mathcal{X_E}\;\mathrm{is\;countable}\\
\;\\
\int_{\mathcal{X_E}} P(x)dx\;\;\mathrm{Otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

With this notation you can also redefine your conditional expectation,
$$
\mathbb{E}[A|E] = \mathbb{E}[A|x \in \mathcal{X_E}]
$$

Once you know $E$ you should be able to define the set $\mathcal{X_E}$.  In the trivial case that $E(x)$ was invertible, $\mathcal{X_E}$ would only contain a single number.  Sampling from $P(X|E)$ can be accomplished with Monte-Carlo, Metropolis-Hastings, or direct calculation depending upon the nature of $\mathcal{X_E}$.

You can then write the conditional expectation as
$$
 \mathbb {E}[A|x \in \mathcal{X_E}] =\begin{cases}
\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X_E}} A(x) \frac{P(X)}{P(E)}\;\; \mathrm{if} \;\; \mathcal{X_E}\;\mathrm{is\;countable} \\ 
\; \\
\int_{\mathcal{X_E}} A(x) \frac{P(X)}{P(E)}dx \;\; \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases} 
$$
and under some regularity conditions this would be a consistent estimator.

To address your concerns in comment (B), it may very well be more computationally efficient to simulate a joint distribution $(A(x_i),E(x_i))$ if you want to estimate the conditional value of $A$ in respect to many $E^*$.  In such a setting you could either average $A(x_i)$ over a weighted sample (with larger weights assigned to values closer to $E^*$), or average $A$ over a smaller sub-sample interval around $E^*$. Whether or not this technique is efficient in the statistical sense depends a lot on the functions you are using. I think it would be a consistent estimator....but I am not entirely sure.

I guess part of the problem is that I do not know what functions you are using.  If, for example, $E(x) = x^2$ (totally trivial I know...) then it would be easy to implement the technique I discussed above.  With very complicated functions I could see how it would be a total pain, especially if you had to implement an MCMC for each individual  $E^*$.

Comment: A) This derivation is in spirit equivalent to the above for discrete $E$. In step 1, shouldn't it be that $P(X=x|E) = \delta_{x \in \chi_E} P(X=x)/P(E)$ where $\delta$ is the Kronecker-delta? Otherwise, for a given $E$, when $x \notin \chi_E$, $P(X=x|E) = P(x)/P(E) \neq 0$, while it should be $P(X=x|E) = 0$ (another way to see is that marginalising $x$ (over $\chi$), does not give 1. The Kronecker-delta enforces that the marginal is only over $\chi_E$. When $E$ is continuous, the Kronecker-delta is replaced by the Dirac-delta because $P(E=E(x)|x)=\delta(E-E(x))$ fulfils $\int P(E|x) dE = 1$.

Comment: B) that in practice I don't need to know $P(E)$ is true if I want to estimate the mean for a fixed $E^*$ only. In that case you are right: I only accept states inside $\chi_{E^*}$. However, I want to estimate the mean as a function of $E$, and it would be inefficient to run a MC simulation for every value of $E$: even sampling $x$ from $P(x)$ already gives pairs $(E(x_i),A(x_i))$ that can be used to estimate the mean of A for each value of $E$. I'm using MH with a weight (e.g. $e^{-\beta E}$) to favor some regions of $E$, but this will not change the fact that I have a ratio of two estimates.

Comment: (A) I was lazy with my notation.  The answer  is yes but in many disciplines, the fact that $P(X|E) =0$ for $x \not\in \mathcal{X_E}$ is implied.  I changed my notation in the answer and hopefully that helps.  (B) See edits, I sympathize

Comment: Thank you for the comment and the edit. "...but I am not entirely sure." My exact feeling. :-) Yes, $E$ in my case is a complicated function: e.g. it has a zero-measure set of minima whose dimension is non-integer (a fractal set). If you are curious, these functions appear in chaotic systems, systems that I've been sampling, e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.4672

Comment: @J.C.Leitão I have no experience with chaotic systems.  I would say that if you could easily find the set $\mathcal{X_E}$ then the method I proposed would be more efficient. Using plain MC on the joint will estimate the conditional mean with values that fall outside of $\mathcal{X_E}$ which could potentially lead to some inefficiencies.  Informally, if you only sampled from an epsilon ball around $E^*$, as the ball became arbitrarily small, your sample would converge on $P(A|E^*)$, so you may be able to establish consistency with that sort of logic.

Comment: However, if the topology of the functions are very rough, the estimator could potentially be very inaccurate in any reasonably sized finite sample.  It would probably be a good idea to run a simulation, and see what your empirical estimates do as you increase the sample size of your MC, ideally they will converge onto the true value.

Comment: Though the estimator I proposed may be a pain from a computational standpoint, it is easy to show, under weak regularity conditions, that it is a consistent estimator, and it may have more desirable small sample properties since it only samples from $\mathcal{X_E}$.  Furthermore, it would be easy to approximate the standard error of this estimator with Taylor series approximations, such as the Delta method, or with Edgeworth approximations.  As I said previously, I know nothing about Chaos theory, so I could be way off, but that would be my two cents anyway.